# Can't get a picture from web-cam with OpenCV when Asus Xtion Pro is plugged in

Tags: c++, opencv, openni

I can get an image from web-cam (Microsot HD-3000) with OpenCV and everything works fine, when Xtion isn't plug in USB of computer, but if I just plug it in I get only a gray image from web-cam. Skype can't get image too. Xtion works well with OpenNI 2. I use Windows 7 x86 on my Computer and OpenCV 2.4.0.

Comment: i don't think it's a c++/opencv problem if skype also don't work.

Comment: maybe, but i forgot to mention that I still can can get image from web-cam with "Honestech DVR 2.5", but not in OpenCV program

Comment: @kosign can you post a bit code illustrating how you've attempted to access the Xtion device and webcam ? You're trying to use both at the same time, correct ?

Comment: Yes, it is my main target, but I can't get image from webcam even without access to Xtion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are likely facing is the limitation of the USB bus. Especially Microsoft lifecams are sensitive to this problem as they tend to grab the maximum bus speed they can. If they can't do this they stop working. The solution to this can be either very simple or a little more complicated.

**1:** Switch around USB plugs. Some mainboards have different USB buses on different ports. By swapping around you might be able to find a configuration that does work for you.

**2:** Expand your system with another USB bracket. If the solution in 1 doesn't work you're going to have to expand your computer with more USB ports to get around the bus limitation.

**3:** Use as less USB devices as possible, don't use the ASUS Xtion, or buy a different webcam

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried 1 and it doesn't work for me. As for 3 I use only USB mouse, Xtion and webcam. And it is strange, but I can get image from webcam with "Honestech DVR 2.5" program. I tried my code on another PC and it works perfectly even when I get images from webcam and Xtion at the same time.

Comment: Then my best guess is that option 2 works for you. Have you ever gotten images from both webcam and Xtion on your own system? That would mean that it is physically possible, but not with openCV. Have you tried a different brand webcam (for instance Logitech)?

Comment: Yes, I've got images from both webcam (with "Honestech DVR 2.5" program) and Xtion (with my program with OpenNI and OpenCV). I tried SmartTrack EZ-LOOK webcam and it doesn't work neither. Yesterday I tried a Chinese noname webcam and it works(!). But quality of image leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: In that case I think that the way OpenCV makes use of the Microsoft camera is competing with the Xtion at least on your current system. Perhaps you can use a different method to grab the frames, but probably using a Logitech webcam or adding a USB bracket will be easier and also does the trick.

Comment: I tried USB bracket and it doesn't work, the same with logitech camera. I tried Genius iLook 110 and it works like Chinese webcam. I think they work with Xtion because they are both USB 1.1 while others webcams I tried are USB 2.0.

Comment: Strange that the USB bracket doesn't work, in theory that should have also solved it if the USB 1.1 would work while 2.0 doesn't. Have you tried a powered USB hub? I managed to get two Kinect systems working on one laptop, while on another this doesn't work because of a limitation of the USB ports...